# How to divide each value of matrix by square root of sums of Respective columns of that matrix?

Tags: r

How I can obtained by dividing each original value by the square root of the sum of squared original values for that column in the original matrix.

```
data(longley)
X <- as.matrix(longley[,-7])

X/sqrt(colSums(X^2))
```

Getting wrong results.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is wrong with the result.

Comment: `sqrt(colSums(X^2))` is fine ( and much faster than `apply`) but when doing `X/...` the result from `sqrt(colSums(X^2))` are recycled accross the columns and so you get "wrong results".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this work?

```
data(longley)
X <- as.matrix(longley[,-7])

X <- apply(X, 2 , function(x) x/sqrt(sum(x^2)))
```

Comment: There is a typo in your anonymous function. It should be a lower-case x in the sum.

Comment: Thanks. There is simple typing mistake 
X <- apply(X, 2 , function(x) x/sqrt(sum(x^2)))
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
t(t(X)/sqrt(colSums(X^2)))
```

**Benchmarks:**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(t(t(X)/sqrt(colSums(X^2))),
               apply(X, 2 , function(x) x/sqrt(sum(x^2))))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                      expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
# t(t(X)/sqrt(colSums(X^2)))                 28.783  33.1305  34.9455  40.5640  68.147   100
# apply(X, 2, function(x) x/sqrt(sum(x^2))) 100.307 105.1940 106.9975 108.1075 193.015   100
```

Comment: this is faster and it also gives the idea of how in algebra such operations are performed.

Comment: As expected! `colSums` vs `apply(X,2,sum)` is known to be faster . (anyway, already upvoted)